Coupling exchange constant for different values of spin S
The $1$D Ising model can be extended to a transverse external magnetic field, reads:
$H = -J\sum_{\langle i, j\rangle} \sigma_{ix}\sigma_{jx} - B^z\sum_i\sigma_{zi}$,
where $J$ are the coupling constant between nearest-neighbors, $\sigma_{ix}$ the Pauli matrice of spin $i$ along the $x$-axis and $B^z$ the transverse magnetic field. This model present a quantum critical point at $B^z \approx J$. The Hamiltonian presented here can be extended to another values of spin, like spin-1 or spin-3/2. What I want to know is how these different values of spin change the position (J/B) of the critical point. Could anyone help me?
Thanks!!!
